# CSS Button Style into Text Style

Tags: html, css

I'm using this piece of CSS to style a button.

Is there any way to also style text with it?

Without losing any of the effects?

The button I'm referring to: (#1)
https://webdeasy.de/en/top-css-buttons-en/

```css
.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary {
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #111;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:before {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left:-2px;
    background-size: 400%;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:active {
    color: #000
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:active:after {
    background: transparent;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #111;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 400% 0; }
    100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
```

```html
<button class="drts-bs-btn-outline-primary" type="button">HOVER ME, THEN CLICK ME!</button>
```

Can't find a solution for this

Comment: can you add a code snipet with the html and the css so that we can test it?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to overwrite the [default style](https://ishadeed.com/article/styling-the-good-old-button/#the-default-styles) using `!important`. Follow the link to learn more.

```css
button {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: green!important;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary {
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #111;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:before {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left:-2px;
    background-size: 400%;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:active {
    color: #000
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:active:after {
    background: transparent;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #111;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 400% 0; }
    100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
```

```html
<button class="drts-bs-btn-outline-primary" type="button">HOVER ME, THEN CLICK ME!</button>
```